# Prestashop 1.7 - array() categories in order-confirmation.tpl

Tags: product, categories, prestashop-1.7, confirmation

I would like to add **conditions for specific category** in **order-confirmation.tpl**

I **can show only the default category** like this :

`{if $product.id_category_default == 374} Yippee-ki-yay {/if}`

But i must to do with **associated categories** like this :

```
{if in_array(374,Product::getProductCategories($product.id|intval))}Yippee-ki-yay{/if}
```

**Thx for everything**

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new module and implement the orderConfirmation hook:

```
  public function hookOrderConfirmation($params)
    {
        $order = $params['order'];
        $products = $order->getCartProducts();
        $flag = false;
        foreach($products as $product){
            if(in_array(374, Product::getProductCategories($product->id))) {
                $flag = true;
            }
        }
         $this->smarty->assign(array(
                'myCustomFlag' => $flag,
         ));
    }
```

And you can use the 'myCustomFlag' variable in the order-confirmation.tpl

```
{if $myCustomFlag} Yippee-ki-yay {/if}
```

Comment: Thx for your anwer,  an interesting way

Comment: an interesting way, but not exactly what i need, it's only for a specific category here

I need to do 
{if $myCustomFlag == 374} Yippee-ki-yay 1 {/if}
{if $myCustomFlag == 403} Yippee-ki-yay 2 {/if}
...